#  What data is passed to the callback function called from FB.ui( )?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

So [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/) shows this:

```
FB.ui(
  {
    method: 'feed',
    name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
    link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
    description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.'
  },
  function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
      alert('Post was published.');
    } 
  }
);
```

That's great. But I can't find any documentation on what's in that `response` variable that's passed to the callback function. Is that documented anywhere? Specifically, I'd like a way to retrieve how many users a link was just "shared" to. **Although the code above uses the "feed" method, I'm using the "send" method.**

Comment: `console.log(response)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/ and see `Return Data` section

Comment: That's for the "feed" method. I'm using "send". Is the same info relevant?

Comment: @Emerson: I see `method: 'feed',` in your question

Comment: It's in the code, because it's the closest example I could find in the documentation, but the last sentence in the question clarifies.

Comment: @Emerson: so change it to what you need your code to be and use `console.log(arguments)`. There is nothing in documentation